# Is there a way to know if a specific kernel boot parameter is supported on a specific linux kernel version

Tags: linux, kernel

I would like to know if a specific kernel boot parameter is supported on specific kernel version. For example is there a way to know what are the kernel parameters available for a specific kernel version and what parameters were added on new versions .

To give more specific example : on which kernel version is rcu_nocbs was added.

Comment: You would have to read the source. Any options not supported have no effect.

Comment: It seems the kernel boot option `rcu_nocbs` is supported with enabled `CONFIG_RCU_NOCB_RCU` configuration option: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v3.8/source/init/Kconfig#L657. That configuration option has been introduced in Linux Kernel 3.8.

Comment: @Tsyvarev does your comment mean that the option is just available as a configuration option when compiling the kernel from 3.8 onwards, and would require someone to enable the option when compiling the kernel, or that the option is enabled in all kernels from 3.8 onwards? E.g. I'm trying to figure out if Debian 12/proxmox kernels support the `rcu_nocbs` option in the boot parameters, or if I would need to compile my own kernel in order to know for sure setting this in the grub boot config has an effect.

Comment: @Programster: "the option is enabled in all kernels from 3.8 onwards" - Would an option be enabled in every kernel, it wouldn't be an **option**, don't you think so? You need to examine configuration of the particular distro to check whether the option is enabled in it.